# What does the "|" operator do?

Tags: methods, syntax, operators, operator-keyword

I don't get this operator. What does it do?

Here is an example of where I find it:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

Answer (score 4):

That's bitwise OR.  It's useful in this case for composing bitmasks.  Those flags are defines for a number which has one bit set, and when you OR them together, you end up with a number with both bits set.

example:
I don't know what the exact value of those flags is, but let's imagine they are:

```
#define GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT  0x01
#define GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT  0x08
```

If you write those out in binary, you get:

```
GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT = 00000001
GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT = 00001000
```

And if you bitwise OR those together, you set the bit in the output to 1 if that bit is set in either `GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT` **OR** `GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT`, so:

```
GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT = 00000001
GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT = 00001000
                    = 00001001
```

So you end up with the number 0x09.

The function you're calling will examine the number you passed in, and based on which bits are set, it knows what flags you're passing in.

Comment: Can you explain in a little more detail on exactly what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

It is a bitwise or operator. Bitwise or works in a way shown below:

Lets assume you have 2 bytes a,b.

```
a = 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1

b = 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0
```

Bitwise operators work on a `bit level`. What happens is it takes each bit in turn and performs an or operation on it. If at least one (or both) bits are 1s the the corresponding bit in the result byte will also be a one. If they are both 0 then result bit will also be 0.

So a bitwise or on a and b will do this:

```
a = 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1

b = 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0

c = 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1
```

First bit 0 and 1. There is a 1 so bit in c will be a 1.
Second bit 0 and 0 so next result bit will be a 0.
Third bit both 1s. At least one 1 is present so next bit in c will be a 1... and so on.

Hope it clears it up for you.

PS. I used dummy bits here and by no means they correspond to the actual values used by `GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT` or `GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT`.

Mostly bitwise operators are used to enforce a mask on a value or combine two values together.

`|` will combine the two together
`&` will enforce a mask

Lets assume you are given a value and you want to make it look like this (we will use `&` to enforce that mask).

```
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0
```

0s will correspond to places where there should be no value and 1s correspond to the bits which you are interested in and want to extact.

```
   a = 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0
mask = 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0
```

Now all bits in a which are above 0s will be dropped and result will have 0s in these bits because for and & you need both bits to be 1s to result in a bit 1.

Where you have 1s in the mask, thats where the potential 1s in result will occur. So using & on each bit you end up with this value.

```
result = 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0
```

If you look closer the 4 bits in result which are in same position as 1s in mask are simply moved from a. So what it really did was removed the bits in a where mask had a 0 and kept the ones with 1s.

Answer (score 0):

It depends a bit on the language you are using, but in many this is the [bitwise or](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR). This is often used to pass several flags that are encoded as a bit into a function. For instance if you have two flags

```
const char FLAG_1 = 0x01;
const char FLAG_2 = 0x02;
```

then `FLAG_1 | FLAG_2` is `0x03`. For bitwise disjoint bits this is equivalent to addition, which is can be confusing at first. In the call the bits are or'd

```
func( FLAG_1 | FLAG_2) // set both FLAG_1 and FLAG_2
```

The function `func` can then test the bits individually using the [bitwise and](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND):

```
void func( char flags ) {
     if( flag & FLAG_1 ) { // test for FLAG_1
     }
     if( flag & FLAG_1 ) { // test for FLAG_2
     }
}
```